# Can I specify when my video shall start on html?

Tags: html, video, embed

I want my video to show a specified image while embedding it on html
basically I'm doing the following:

`<embed src="video.m4v" width="520" height="456" autoplay="false" controller="true" type="video/quicktime" scale="tofit" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"  bgcolor="black"> </embed>`

Is there a specific parameter that I can add that says when the video shall start?

Answer (score 0):

There are no attributes of the `embed` tag that specify the start time of what's embedded.

Depending on what's playing your video, you could use a `param` tag with `flashvars`.